# How to find the nth max salary from different departments?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying find the nth largest salary for every department from the list. I am able to do the basic min and max using aggregation e.g.

```
Select DEPARTMENT, MAX(SALARY) FROM dept_salary
GROUP BY 1
```

Using MySQL I'm able to get nth salary based on individual but not combined:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENT, SALARY FROM dept_salary
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT n,1

DEPARTMENT         SALARY
-------------------------
Customer Service   143937
Human Resources    141953
Customer Service   138637
Customer Service   137535
Customer Service   136548
Customer Service   135650
Marketing          135497
Customer Service   134893
Customer Service   133837
Customer Service   133569
```

Any pointer on how to get this to work is kindly appreciated.

Comment: This does look a lot like homework. Are you sure we should be doing it for you?

Comment: @codeBarer Also, if this IS a homework/exam/interview question, you would be well advised to mention it, because, while gordons answer is correct and fast and probably the best solution for any real world problem, will usually not score you the maximum points because it is not using just standard sql (sets), which is often a boundary condition on tests.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks, I am trying to prepare for an interview so I came up with the above question on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general solution, variables are the simplest method:

```
select ds.*
from (select ds.*,
             (@rn := if(@d = department, @rn + 1,
                        if(@d := department, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select distinct department, salary
            from dept_salary
           ) ds cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @d := '') params
      order by department, salary desc
     ) ds
where rn = 3;  -- for instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to group by department:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT, MAX(SALARY) AS max_salary FROM dept_salary
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT
ORDER BY SALARY DESC
```

Comment: This is will not help to find nth salary for each department

Comment: Sorry for using `group by` after order by, now its working fine

Comment: Still it is wrong.. check the question OP always doesn't want max salary for each department. nth salary for each department `n` can be any number

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 DISTINCT(salary) 
from dept_salary
 order by salary desc 
limit 1,1
```

Comment: Always, always post explanations with your answers.  Code-only posts are low-quality because they do very little to educate readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @nthMaxSalary = 2;

select ctr,dept,salary from (
select @rowCtr := if(@dept = dept,@rowCtr +1,1) as ctr
,@dept := dept dept
,salary
from dept_salary
order by dept,salary desc
  ) t where ctr = @nthMaxSalary ;
```